# Cordova/Android: Determine if geo: scheme link would open any maps app

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

I am providing `geo:` links to open a location in an external maps app, which works fine in general. If no maps (neither google maps, osmand, etc) is installed, the link just doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to determine if `geo:` links could be opened after clicking it, or any app handling `geo:` links is installed, so I could display a meaningful message?

I guess I could assume on iOS a maps app must be installed.